# Buttons don't get pressed by touch events in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Very simple.

Create a couple of large buttons on an AnchorPane in Scenebuilder (no need to go all the way to compiling an app). Preview your scene.
You'll find the buttons don't respond to touch on Windows 8, unless you drag down on the button. Then you'll see the **:pressed** style come up.

Best make the style obviously different as it's a bit hard to tell with the slight different shades of default grey.

In my app, navigating the nodes in the scene and adding an onAction event, but that makes no difference as I said the problem already manifests in scene builder.

I'm looking for a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: That's so weird,  I recommend checking the [JavaFX bug tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) and filing a bug report if this has not been reported previously.  Also try the [latest Gluon SceneBuilder version](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-supports-scene-builder/) and see if the issue manifests itself there.

Comment: Apparently I'm on an old version (build 1.8.0_05-b13), so I'll update and report back.

Comment: Tried with (build 1.8.0_40-b26), still broken.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to use onAction, so instead do something like this in the code

```
//  button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)-> runnable.run());
    button.setOnTouchPressed((TouchEvent event) ->  button.getStyleClass().add("buttonPressed"));
    button.setOnTouchReleased((TouchEvent event) -> {
      button.getStyleClass().remove("buttonPressed");
      runnable.run();
    });
```

and then in the stylesheet

```
/* do this */
.buttonPressed {...}
/* not this */
.button:pressed {...}
```